# Populating a database with file names from directories

Tags: c++, sql, c++builder

I have an application which behaves as a slideshow for all pictures in a folder.  It is written in Borland's C++ Builder (9). It currently uses some borrowed code to throw the filenames into a listbox and save the listbox items as a text file.

I want to update this so that the filenames are stored in a proper database so that I can include extra fields and do proper SQL things with it.

So basically I would be able to work it out if I saw some 'sample' code doing the same thing.

So if anyone knows of any code that does this I would be greatful.  It needs to be able to do it on certain file types... not just all the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically neeed to write a recursive function with a TDataSet parameter.

(I could not compile my code, so you get it "as is")

```
void AddFiles(AnsiString path, TDataSet *DataSet)
{
TSearchRec sr;
int f;
    f = FindFirst(path+"\\*.*", faAnyFile, sr);
    while( !f )
    {
        if(sr.Attr & faDirectory)
        {
            if(sr.Name != "."   &&   sr.Name != "..")
            {
                path.sprintf("%s%s%s", path, "\\", sr.Name);
                AddFiles(path, DataSet);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            DataSet->Append();
            DataSet->FieldByName("Name")->Value = sr.Name;
            /* other fields ... */
            DataSet->Post();
        }
        f = FindNext(sr);
    }
    FindClose(sr);
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for this.  I'll try it out when I can which unfortunately is not immediately.  I'll let you know the outcome.

Comment: I got around to testing this code (albeit without the dataset stuff - just to test getting all files in a dir and it's subdirs) and it doesn't work properly.    It messes up the paths...

real structure

a
a\b
a\c
a\d

becomes

a
a\b
a\b\c

(it incorrectly makes a subdir of 'a' into a subdir of 'b'